# How to setup a solution with two Web API Projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm in charge of porting a Java application to .Net platform. 
I'm kinda experienced with C# and .Net but I've never started building things like this from scratch.

So, this application consists of two parts:

- **Framework:** A small framework responsible for creating CRUD pages endpoints. This framework uses classes from the "business layer" as models in order to easy build pages. It basically has a `FrameworkPage<T>` class and we use a type `T` and some overridings in order to write it. Also, this framework has some endpoints of its own. Like `myapp/framework/FirstPage` which maps to a `framework/{pageName}` controller where we use a generic logic to retrieve data for that page. The important part is that this framework has its own endpoints.
- **Business Layer**: Application that uses the above framework, has its business classes and also has its own custom endpoints for pages that are not the default framework page.

Today, in the Java project, these two are only separated in different folders. In the future we want to reuse the framework wherever we want, so it is important to keep it dettached from any business logic. To do so, in .Net platform, I think it would be interesting to have these two in separated projects inside my solution. Then, in the future would be easy to separate it and even compile it into a `dll` to use in another projects.

Is this the right approach? If so, how can I make it possible since I'm having two web apis applications? As far as I know about a .Net project configuration, I have only one startup project (the one that is deployed). I can set a multiple startup configuration on those guys but I could only get them to be started as separated apps: `localhost:XXXX/myapp` and `localhost:YYYY/framework`. I need the framework to go "inside" the application: `localhost:XXX/myapp/framework/framework-endpoint`.

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing classes between APIs is always a bit of a problem I have found.Lots of projects I come across implement much the same method as I have always done which is to maintain models in both the caller and the receiver API. There could easily be a better way to achieve this but I don't really have enough knowledge on this to confidently suggest a potential solution. With regards to the startup configuration, how are you running these web applications? I often run multiple APIs with routing similar to your own, I achieve through building in VS and pointing the web server config to the location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution that suits me by using `AddApplicationPart()`.
Basically, on the `Startup.cs` of my `BusinessLayerProject` I configure the services as:

```
using Framework.Controllers;

// ....

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(FrameworkController1).Assembly)
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(FrameworkController2).Assembly)
    // ...
    .AddControllersAsServices();
```

With this, if my framework controller has a route like `framework/controller1` I can access it when I deploy the `BusinessLayerProject`